# What type of clothing is required when working around asbestos?

Tags: safety, asbestos

I find myself exploring environments rich in Asbestos, the specific type of asbestos appears to be both pipes and potentially the cladding around them (steam pipes etc), occasionally broken sheets as well. From time to time I'm required to crawl through these types of environments and there is a large amount of dust kicked up in the process. I'm not sure exactly *what* type of dust this is but since there are numerous warning signs about asbestos in the area I'm fairly certain at least a portion of it is hazardous.

I'm familiar with using respirators with P2/P2N filters however I'm unsure about clothing requirements.

1) If I were to do the above in general-day-to-day clothing and get dust/fibers in my clothing, **will thoroughly washing remove the fibers?** Do any potential remaining fibers pose a health risk? How can I tell if there are any fibers in my clothes?

2) How do you know when to replace respirator filters (I'm thinking of the face masks with dual cartridges)?

Comment: If you even suspect that asbestos may be present wear a disposable Tyvec coverall and throw it away after each use. Even if washing did remove the fibers your house, vehicle and everywhere in between could be contaminated.

Comment: if you wash the fibers out of your clothes, where will the fibers go after the wash? probably not a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this PDF from the Australian government (assuming the +61 in your profile means OZ)

Pages 29 and 30 deal with personal protective equipment. (PDF pages 42-43 AND WHY CAN"T ANY MAKE PDF page numbers work!!!)

[Asbestos Removal Guidlines](http://www.finance.wa.gov.au/cms/uploadedFiles/Building_Management_and_Works/safe_removal_asbestos_cop.pdf?n=3439)

I'll highlight this line:  **The laundering of contaminated protective clothing in workers’ homes is strictly prohibited.**

Generally though, this is a workplace safety issue, and I'd contact the Ministry of Labour.